# start-dfs.sh -not working - localhost: Bad port 'localhost' (Hadoop 2.7.1)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ubuntu-14.10

I have installed hadoop 2.7.1 on ubuntu 14.10

When i try the command hadoop version - its working fine.

hadoop namenode -format command is also working fine

The command start-dfs.sh - not working

I am getting

Starting namenodes on [localhost]

localhost: Bad port 'localhost'

localhost: Bad port 'localhost'

Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]

0.0.0.0: Bad Port '0.0.0.0'

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

`host file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   hp-HP-Notebook

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

hadoop namenode -format

```
hp@hp-HP-Notebook:~$ hadoop namenode -format
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

16/01/19 22:15:18 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = hp-HP-Notebook/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.7.1
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.1-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.1-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 15ecc87ccf4a0228f35af08fc56de536e6ce657a; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2015-06-29T06:04Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_79
************************************************************/
16/01/19 22:15:18 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
16/01/19 22:15:18 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-format]
Formatting using clusterid: CID-beba2328-b534-4370-9f89-d5b3fc3c9986
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: No KeyProvider found.
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair:true
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=true
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.namenode.startup.delay.block.deletion.sec is set to 000:00:00:00.000
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: The block deletion will start around 2016 Jan 19 22:15:21
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 889 MB = 17.8 MB
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: shouldCheckForEnoughRacks  = false
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = hp (auth:SIMPLE)
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
16/01/19 22:15:21 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO util.GSet: 1.0% max memory 889 MB = 8.9 MB
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: ACLs enabled? false
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: XAttrs enabled? true
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: Maximum size of an xattr: 16384
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map cachedBlocks
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO util.GSet: 0.25% max memory 889 MB = 2.2 MB
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^18 = 262144 entries
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.window.num.buckets = 10
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.num.users = 10
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.windows.minutes = 1,5,25
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 889 MB = 273.1 KB
16/01/19 22:15:22 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory /usr/local/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode ? (Y or N) y
16/01/19 22:15:28 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-1331619148-127.0.1.1-1453221928666
16/01/19 22:15:28 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /usr/local/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode has been successfully formatted.
16/01/19 22:15:29 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
16/01/19 22:15:29 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
16/01/19 22:15:29 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at hp-HP-Notebook/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Comment: can you paste the core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml file

Comment: @KishoreKumarSuthar, i have pasted the core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml

Comment: check if any other service is started on 9000 port

Comment: paste hadoop namenode -format console and vi /etc/hosts file

Comment: i have pasted the above said details

Comment: have you updated fs.default.name in core-site.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

> core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

> hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
 <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

> hadoop-env.sh
>   
>   export JAVA_HOME= set path
>   export HADOOP_HOME= set path
>
> yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
 <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>


<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
 <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
```

> hadoop namenode -format
>   ./start-all.sh

Comment: No changes were reflected...Error still the same